# Xcode: Linker command error when installing frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, ssziparchive

I'm trying to use the framework SSZipArchive. I tried to "install" it via cocoaPods (I couldn't make it) and, later, I tried via Carthage. I thought that the second option had had installed it, but It didn't. It gives me this error:

> Ld /Users/alumno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/webR-enbsuevwixwhtweyjzzmrsectubh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/webR.app/webR normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/alumno/Documents/iosProj/webR
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/alumno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/webR-enbsuevwixwhtweyjzzmrsectubh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/alumno/Documents/iosProj/webR/Pods/GGLInstanceID/Libraries -L/Users/alumno/Documents/iosProj/webR/Pods/Google/Libraries -L/Users/alumno/Documents/iosProj/webR/Pods/GoogleCloudMessaging/Libraries -L/Users/alumno/Documents/iosProj/webR/Pods/GoogleIPhoneUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/alumno/Documents/iosProj/webR/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/alumno/Documents/iosProj/webR/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/alumno/Documents/iosProj/webR/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/alumno/Documents/iosProj/webR/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries -F/Users/alumno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/webR-enbsuevwixwhtweyjzzmrsectubh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alumno/Documents/iosProj/webR/Carthage/Build/iOS -filelist /Users/alumno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/webR-enbsuevwixwhtweyjzzmrsectubh/Build/Intermediates/webR.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/webR.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/webR.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lGGLCloudMessaging -lGGLCore -lGGLInstanceIDLib -lGIP_Locale -lGIP_Reachability -lGSDK_Overload_external -lGTMSessionFetcher_core_external -lGTMSessionFetcher_full_external -lGTMStackTrace_external -lGTM_AddressBook_external -lGTM_DebugUtils_external -lGTM_GTMURLBuilder_external -lGTM_KVO_external -lGTM_NSData+zlib -lGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments_external -lGTM_NSScannerJSON_external -lGTM_NSStringHTML_external -lGTM_NSStringXML_external -lGTM_Regex_external -lGTM_RoundedRectPath_external -lGTM_StringEncoding_external -lGTM_SystemVersion_external -lGTM_UIFont+LineHeight_external -lGTM_core_external -lGTM_iPhone_external -lGcmLib -lProtocolBuffers_external -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lz -framework AddressBook -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMotion -framework MessageUI -framework SSZipArchive -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -force_load -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/alumno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/webR-enbsuevwixwhtweyjzzmrsectubh/Build/Intermediates/webR.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/webR.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/webR.swiftmodule -framework ZipArchive -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/alumno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/webR-enbsuevwixwhtweyjzzmrsectubh/Build/Intermediates/webR.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/webR.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/webR_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/alumno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/webR-enbsuevwixwhtweyjzzmrsectubh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/webR.app/webR
>
> ld: framework not found SSZipArchive 
>   clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

These are the steps I made:

1- Create the carpfile and add this line:

```
github "ZipArchive/ZipArchive"
```

2- Install it through the Terminal by this command:

```
carthage update --platform iOS
```

3- Link the Frameworks and Libraries on the project options.

4- On the Build phases run a script:

```
Shell: /bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
Input Files: $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/ZipArchive.framework
```

5- Now I can use the import rightly but, when I build the project, It gives me the error below.

EDIT: Do you know any tool to unzip downloaded data that supports iOS 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, It works! I just didn't know that I must especify on the build phases the files that must be copied (the framework). I'll lend you a screenshoot of that, maybe can be helpful for somebody.

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBp8k.png)

TY